# Reference a for loop item outside for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to break up my huge function by making smaller functions, which are then called in the main function.

The issue I am having is that the big function is almost entirely a for x in list loop, and I need to reference x throughout the function.

If I split up the code, and call a function which contains x, x is not recognised. Is there anyway to avoid this?

I know for a variable you could make it global, but this isn't a variable.

EDIT:
Thanks for the fast reply guys! Here is an example of what I mean:

```
def func():
  for item in L:
    if varA == 1:
      var1 = "Hello"
    if varB == 1:
      var2 = "World"
```

What I want it to be like:

```
def minifunc1():
  var1 = "Hello"
def minifunc2():
  var1 = "World"

def func():
  for item in L:
    if varA == 1:
      minifunc1()
    if varB == 1:
      minifunc2()
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an XY Problem. Your real problem isn't that you can't reference the current element elsewhere in your code -- it's that you're approaching the question the wrong way!

Comment: do you know how to pass parameters to functions? If so, just pass `x` to each of the functions that use it

Comment: Functions, are variables too. What is x?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class object in Python and have multiple methods that accesses/modifies a particular attribute:

```
class PROJECT(object):

    def __init__(self, alist):
        """
        Instantiate a class object with a single list of numbers
        """ 

        self.alist = alist
        self.result = None

    def multiply(self, value):
        """
        Multiply each element of the list by the value and store it in result
        """

        self.result = [x * value for x in self.alist]

        return 

    def add(self, value):
        """
        Add to each element of the list the passed value and return the list
        """

        return [x + value for x in self.alist]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    test = PROJECT(l)
    test.multiply(5)
    test.add(10)
```